# Restrict background data for Facebook, but notifications still coming in

Tags: facebook, background-data

I would only like particular applications to show notifications when I'm **not on Wifi** and those would be:

- Google Services - unfortunately there are several syncs here but AFAIK we can't control individual ones
- Google Search - I'm not sure what this one does but I suppose I want to keep this one up
- GMail - for obvious reasons

But all of the others I would like to disable. **Including Facebook**.

The problem I'm having is that Facebook notifications are still being displayed on my phone. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you have turned off "Accounts and Sync" from "Settings -> Accounts" ?

Comment: @yrajabi: Facebook account doesn't have such setting.

Comment: It has been known that some apps ignore the "Restrict background data" setting. However, I have this setting turned on for only the facebook app on my SGS2 with ICS and I never get any notifications.

Comment: @THelper are you sure you are talking about *restrict background data*, and not having *background sync* in mind? For the latter, this is true (API says "apps *should* obey" that setting, not they *must*). To my knowledge, it's not for the app to decide whether it has to obey "restrict background data"; rather the system enforces this like a "mini firewall" AFAIK. The point with the FB notifications might be that they are *pushed* from the outside, using the central push service instead of being *polled* by the app (see Dan's answer, *GCM*).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's notifications come through *Google Cloud Messaging* (GCM). As such, the Facebook app itself isn't using the network at all, as all apps' GCM messages come through one connection, owned by the Google Play Services process.

There's no user control for individual GCM endpoints. It's up to Facebook to provide an option for notifications.