# How does "Restrict background data" work?

Tags: mobile-data

In "Settings"->"Data Usage" there is a "Restrict background data" checkbox.

How does it work, exactly? What does "background" mean here? And is this setting enforced by the OS, or is it a hint that the apps [are free to disregard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29080/restrict-background-data-for-facebook-but-notifications-still-coming-in#comment38460_29080) if coded improperly?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, that setting is enforced by the OS (so it's not for the app to decide whether to observe that setting). Put in easy words: Android won't let an app access the network unless it's running in foreground (i.e. the user is interacting with it) with the restriction enabled for it.

Explained with a plastic example: Restrict background data on the *Google Play Store* app (as I did), it won't anymore check for updates in background while you are on mobile data. But it will do so when you're using WiFi. Also, when you call up the app to install something, it will work as long as you keep it in foreground (i.e. not switch to another app while it's still downloading).

Comment: Thanks. So that comment I linked to is wrong?

Comment: I cannot guarantee that, but I would say so. A setting regarding which that would be true is "background sync" (as even the API doc writes "apps *should* obey", not "apps *must* obey). THelper might have mistaken that setting, as the names are quite similar. Thanks for the pointer, I will add a comment there for clarification.

Comment: A quick note on what "foreground" means: usually, in Android, an app is in the foreground if any of its activities are the topmost activity on the screen. The `NetworkPolicyManager` adds an extra constraint that the screen must be on. "The user is interacting with it" suggests that you must be poking the buttons or something, but actually the activity just needs to be visible on the screen with no other app's activities on top of it.

Comment: @sashoalm See the answer I posted on the question you linked for why people might get confused about what the setting does.

Comment: Does this also disable services like Android Device Manager?

Comment: @StephenAngelico I don't know how exactly this functionality is implemented – but I doubt that. How shall Android determine which service would use this – and even more, make sure that service has no other purpose the user doesn't want to restrict?

Comment: Well, I thought the remote lock and erase would have to be a background service. When using Extreme Power Saving mode on my HTC, it says remote locating services will not work. This could understandably be because it suspends a lot of processes, but it also restricts data usage fairly heavily.

Comment: Hey, is there a way to restrict background data in WIFI also?

Comment: @SPRajagopal at least not built-in AFAIK. With root powers and 3rd party apps like *Greenify*, this should be possible.