# Count roaming data

Tags: roaming

I am traveling to foreign country and I have activated data roaming. How can I track data usage in roaming? I want to know if I have used 10% or 50% or more of my data. One way is to write a note about mobile data consumption and then compare it manually. Is there a better way?

Thank you

I use nexus 5x with Android 6.

Comment: Related [how to control monitor and limit bandwidth usage](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86563/how-to-control-monitor-and-limit-bandwidth-usage)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to selectively limit background data usage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43771/16575). You can move the vertical bars (second screenshot, where data usage is reported) to adjust to a given time frame, so no "manual calculation" is required.