# cannot restrict telephone background data specifically for google playstore without restricting all other apps as well

Tags: google-play-store

Lately I noticed in data settings that google playstore is transfering a ton of data in the background while I am connected to telephone network. This costs me money. If I go to playstore's settings there is an option to restrict background data but then it says I must set a data limit to let it work. The problem is that the data limit limits all apps I don't want to limit all apps. I just want to turn off background data only for playstore.

Comment: You could set the limit to an imaginary value (e.g. 10GB), that does the job. Also see: [Google Play updates on mobile connection despite setting](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75881/16575) / [Can you limit data for a number of apps and leave others unlimited?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/133987/16575) / [Is it possible to selectively limit background data usage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43771/16575)